# A blush of shame to the cheek of modesty

Tags: expressions

What is the meaning of the following sentence?
"The incident brought a blush of shame to the cheek of modesty"

Comment: Hello, Kam. Could you provide us with some additional context for this sentence?

Comment: Those with a conscience / those of a more delicate upbringing blushed when they saw (etc) the incident.

Comment: The meaning of the sentence is complicated, however, by the overwrought and parodic character of its allegorical diction. W. S. Gilbert was mocking Victorian prudery, after all, in the following line in his & Sullivan's *Patience:* "there is not one word in that decalet which is calculated to bring the blush of shame to the cheek of modesty." I suspect the echo here is deliberate.

Answer (score 1):

It simply means that

The people who were **modest/shy/sensitive felt ashamed/blushed with shame** because of the incident.